# Mostly known for these three

Tags: riddle, rebus

---

*Known for my taste.*

*Known for my cruelty.*

*Known for being supernatural.*

**((-ED + -LOW + ----SPORT) + ----ER ------FIVE)** (6)

**--ME + --MALE + "-ED"** (4)

---

**Who Am I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are:

> **Bloody Mary** - a name that has 3 key usages matching the text:
>
>  *Known for my taste* - The vodka-and-tomato-juice [cocktail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Mary_(cocktail)).
>
>  *Known for my cruelty* - [Queen Mary I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_I_of_England) of England, persecutor of many Protestant opponents.
>
>  *Known for being supernatural* - The [phantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Mary_(folklore)) of folklore.

The two lines of words with letters omitted, enumerated (6) and (4), can be filled and resolved as follows...

> ((-ED + -LOW + ----SPORT) + ----ER ------FIVE) (6)

> ((**R**ED + **F**LOW + **TRAN**SPORT) + **LETT**ER **TWENTY**FIVE) (6)
>
>  The first bracket here indicates **BLOOD**, the body's *red*, *flow*ing *transport* system for oxygen and other molecules. The second half indicates the *twenty-fifth letter* of the alphabet: **Y**. Together they spell **BLOODY**.

> --ME + --MALE + "-ED" (4)

> **NA**ME + **FE**MALE + "**W**ED" (4)
>
>  '**MARY**' is a *female name* which (thanks @cap in comments) in some accents sounds like 'marry', a synonym of *wed*.

Comment: maybe rot13(JRQ yvxr zneel, jvgu gur dhbgrf zrnavat fbhaqf yvxr)

Comment: @cap Ah, that sounds good to me! Thanks :)

Comment: Well done! Everything looks good. Only exception is that I had rot13(*Yrggre* gjragl svir) in mind. Didn't even think that rot13(ahzore) fitted. But other than that everything is as intended.

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ha, that would be much more direct!